# Comparing two dictionaries and checking how many (key, value) pairs are equal

Tags: python, dictionary, comparison

I have two dictionaries, but for simplification, I will take these two:

```
>>> x = dict(a=1, b=2)
>>> y = dict(a=2, b=2)
```

Now, I want to compare whether each `key, value` pair in `x` has the same corresponding value in `y`. So I wrote this:

```
>>> for x_values, y_values in zip(x.iteritems(), y.iteritems()):
        if x_values == y_values:
            print 'Ok', x_values, y_values
        else:
            print 'Not', x_values, y_values
```

And it works since a `tuple` is returned and then compared for equality.

My questions:

Is this correct? Is there a *better* way to do this? Better not in speed, I am talking about code elegance.

UPDATE: I forgot to mention that I have to check how many `key, value` pairs are equal.

Comment: ``x == y`` should be true according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/5635309/186202

Comment: x == y should be true. One can quickly check in REPL. Please Refer: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Comment: `x == y` should be true according to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict): _"Dictionaries compare equal if and only if they have the same (key, value) pairs (regardless of ordering). Order comparisons (‘<’, ‘<=’, ‘>=’, ‘>’) raise TypeError."_

Answer (score 262, accepted):

If you want to know how many values match in both the dictionaries, you should have said that :)

Maybe something like this:

```
shared_items = {k: x[k] for k in x if k in y and x[k] == y[k]}
print(len(shared_items))
```

Comment: Same error if there is list element for the dict key. I think cmp is better way to do it unless I am missing anything.

Comment: @Mutant that is a different issue. You cannot create a dictionary with a `list` key in the first place. `x = {[1,2]: 2}` will fail. The question already has valid `dicts`.

Comment: @annan: wrong, the question is generic. the **example** in the question description has already "valid dicts". If I post a new question, with same title, but with a different "invalid"  dict, somebody will mark it as duplicate. Downvoting.

Comment: @ribamar the question is "Comparing two dictionaries [...]". The 'invalid dict' above with `list` keys is not valid python code - dict *keys* must be immutable. Therefore you are not comparing dictionaries. If you try and use a list as a dictionary key your code will not run. You have no objects for which to compare. This is like typing `x = dict(23\;dfg&^*$^%$^$%^)` then complaining how the comparison does not work with the dictionary. Of course it will not work. Tim's comment on the other hand is about mutable `values`, hence why I said that these are different issues.

Comment: @annan: Ok, your comment about Mutant's question is correct (I misunderstood your concept of 'valid dict': there's nothing invalid doing `l = [] ; d = {1 : l}`. `d` is valid dictionary and does not work as the same with the proposed solution. But now I see you're not denying that)

Comment: @TimTisdall You can get around the TypeError if you test both keys and items like this: `set(x.keys())` and `set(x.values())`. But, that only works if the dictionary has only one level of keys and values. If you have a nested `{}` or `[]` you'd need to perform the same operation recursively.

Comment: @MikeyE - `set` requires values to be hashable and `dict` requires keys to be hashable.  `set(x.keys())` will always work because keys are required to be hashable, but `set(x.values())` will fail on values that aren't hashable.

Comment: @TimTisdall For comparing dictionaries with unhashable items, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43504568/compare-dictionaries-with-unhashable-or-uncomparable-values-e-g-lists-or-data

Answer (score 229):

```
def dict_compare(d1, d2):
    d1_keys = set(d1.keys())
    d2_keys = set(d2.keys())
    shared_keys = d1_keys.intersection(d2_keys)
    added = d1_keys - d2_keys
    removed = d2_keys - d1_keys
    modified = {o : (d1[o], d2[o]) for o in shared_keys if d1[o] != d2[o]}
    same = set(o for o in shared_keys if d1[o] == d2[o])
    return added, removed, modified, same

x = dict(a=1, b=2)
y = dict(a=2, b=2)
added, removed, modified, same = dict_compare(x, y)
```

Comment: This one actually handles mutable values in the dict!

Comment: When I run this, I still get an error seeing dealing with the mutable values: 
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @Afflatus - `DataFrame`s by design don't allow truthy comparisons (unless it has a length of 1) as they inherit from `numpy.ndarray`.

-credit to http://stackoverflow.com/a/33307396/994076

Answer (score 217):

What you want to do is simply `x == y`

What you do is not a good idea, because the items in a dictionary are not supposed to have any order. You might be comparing `[('a', 1),('b', 1)]` with `[('b', 1), ('a', 1)]` (same dictionaries, different order).

For example, see this:

```
>>> x = dict(a=2, b=2, c=3, d=4)
>>> x
{'a': 2, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
>>> y = dict(b=2, c=3, d=4)
>>> y
{'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
>>> zip(x.iteritems(), y.iteritems())
[(('a', 2), ('c', 3)), (('c', 3), ('b', 2)), (('b', 2), ('d', 4))]
```

The difference is only one item, but your algorithm will see that *all* items are different

Comment: @THC4k, sorry for not mentioning. But I have to check how many values match in both the dictionaries.

Comment: Ok, so based on my update, is my way of doing still incorrect?

Comment: @A A: I added why your's doesn't work when you want to count.

Comment: I see, but in my case both the dictionaries are of same length. And they will always be, because that is how the program works.

Comment: Does not work for ``python3``. Do this as the last line instead: ``list(zip(x.items(), y.items()))``

Comment: As of Python 3.6, dict is orderd out-of-the-box.

Comment: @JochenRitzel: How this works for deep nested dictionaries inside dicts?
 I tried this on deep nested dicts, with exactly the same value but order was different, and comparison failed

Comment: What about 
```In [6]: x = {"key": True}
In [7]: y = {"key": 1}
In [8]: x == y
Out[8]: True
```
?

Answer (score 215):

## `dic1 == dic2`

From [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

> The following examples **all** return a dictionary **equal**  to
> `{"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}`:
>
> ```
> >>> a = dict(one=1, two=2, three=3)
> >>> b = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
> >>> c = dict(zip(['one', 'two', 'three'], [1, 2, 3]))
> >>> d = dict([('two', 2), ('one', 1), ('three', 3)])
> >>> e = dict({'three': 3, 'one': 1, 'two': 2})
> >>> a == b == c == d == e
> True
> ```

> *Providing keyword arguments as in the first example only works for
> keys that are valid Python identifiers. Otherwise, any valid keys can
> be used.*

Valid for `python2` and `python3`.

Comment: I don't agree with @ErkinAlpGüney. Could you provide a proof?

Comment: I disagree with @ErkinAlpGüney.
The official documentation shows that == does indeed compare dictionaries by value, not by address.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Comment: Works for Python 2.7.13

Comment: Does not work with `OrderedDict`: 
```odict=OrderedDict; assert odict([(1, 1), (2, 2)]) == odict([(2, 2), (1, 1)])``` fails!

Comment: @ankostis: `OrderedDict != dict`

Comment: @PedroLobito passing tests is not a proof for the code to be correct.

Comment: @styrofoamfly I'm not following your line of thought, care to clarify?

Comment: @PedroLobito you cannot prove that "for each input the algorithm produces the expected output" (the definition of correctness). The tests prove only that "for some inputs the algorithm produces the expected output".

Comment: Can you please provide an input where this isn't true?

Comment: @PedroLobito make a `dict` with keys mapping to array if you want to see `dict1 == dict2` fail with an error message.

Comment: @JamesHirschorn The answer is only valid for the examples it shows.

Comment: @PedroLobito That is irrelevant. You had asked "Can you please provide an input where this isn't true?", and this is what I was commenting on.

Comment: @JamesHirschorn arrays as keys is not a valid dict, which is why it errors

Comment: @cwongmath True, but that is not what I was suggesting :)

Answer (score 102):

Since it seems nobody mentioned [`deepdiff`](https://pypi.org/project/deepdiff/), I will add it here for completeness. I find it very convenient for getting diff of (nested) objects in general:

#### Installation

```
pip install deepdiff
```

#### Sample code

```
import deepdiff
import json

dict_1 = {
    "a": 1,
    "nested": {
        "b": 1,
    }
}

dict_2 = {
    "a": 2,
    "nested": {
        "b": 2,
    }
}

diff = deepdiff.DeepDiff(dict_1, dict_2)
print(json.dumps(diff, indent=4))
```

#### Output

```
{
    "values_changed": {
        "root['a']": {
            "new_value": 2,
            "old_value": 1
        },
        "root['nested']['b']": {
            "new_value": 2,
            "old_value": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Note about pretty-printing the result for inspection: The above code works if both dicts have the same attribute keys (with possibly different attribute values as in the example). However, if an `"extra"` attribute is present is one of the dicts, `json.dumps()` fails with

```
TypeError: Object of type PrettyOrderedSet is not JSON serializable
```

Solution: use `diff.to_json()` and `json.loads()` / `json.dumps()` to pretty-print:

```
import deepdiff
import json

dict_1 = {
    "a": 1,
    "nested": {
        "b": 1,
    },
    "extra": 3
}

dict_2 = {
    "a": 2,
    "nested": {
        "b": 2,
    }
}

diff = deepdiff.DeepDiff(dict_1, dict_2)
print(json.dumps(json.loads(diff.to_json()), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "dictionary_item_removed": [
        "root['extra']"
    ],
    "values_changed": {
        "root['a']": {
            "new_value": 2,
            "old_value": 1
        },
        "root['nested']['b']": {
            "new_value": 2,
            "old_value": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Alternative: use `pprint`, results in a different formatting:

```
import pprint

# same code as above

pprint.pprint(diff, indent=4)
```

Output:

```
{   'dictionary_item_removed': [root['extra']],
    'values_changed': {   "root['a']": {   'new_value': 2,
                                           'old_value': 1},
                          "root['nested']['b']": {   'new_value': 2,
                                                     'old_value': 1}}}
```

Comment: This should be on the top. Worked perfectly and is neat!

Answer (score 65):

I'm new to python but I ended up doing something similar to @mouad

```
unmatched_item = set(dict_1.items()) ^ set(dict_2.items())
len(unmatched_item) # should be 0
```

The XOR operator (`^`) should eliminate all elements of the dict when they are the same in both dicts.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if the values in the dict are mutable (ie not hashable).  (Ex `{'a':{'b':1}}` gives `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`)

Answer (score 49):

Just use:

```
assert cmp(dict1, dict2) == 0
```

Comment: It seems that the task is not only to check if the contents of both are the same but also to give a report of the differences

Comment: I believe this is identical to `dict1 == dict2`

Comment: For anyone using Python3.5, the `cmp` built in has been removed (and should be treated as [removed before](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons). An alternative they propose: `(a > b) - (a < b) == cmp(a, b)` for a functional equivalent (or better `__eq__` and `__hash__`)

Comment: can we use cmp(dict1,dict2) for comparing dictionaries with values as unordered list like: dict1={'a':[0,1]} and dict2={'b':[1,0]}?

Comment: @nerdwaller - dicts are not orderable types, so dict_a > dict_b would raise a `TypeError`: `unorderable types: dict() < dict()`

Comment: @Stefano: Good call, my comment was more for general comparison in python (I wasn't paying attention to the actual answer, my mistake) .

Answer (score 11):

@mouad 's answer is nice if you assume that both dictionaries contain simple values only. However, if you have dictionaries that contain dictionaries you'll get an exception as dictionaries are not hashable.

Off the top of my head, something like this might work:

```
def compare_dictionaries(dict1, dict2):
     if dict1 is None or dict2 is None:
        print('Nones')
        return False

     if (not isinstance(dict1, dict)) or (not isinstance(dict2, dict)):
        print('Not dict')
        return False

     shared_keys = set(dict1.keys()) & set(dict2.keys())

     if not ( len(shared_keys) == len(dict1.keys()) and len(shared_keys) == len(dict2.keys())):
        print('Not all keys are shared')
        return False


     dicts_are_equal = True
     for key in dict1.keys():
         if isinstance(dict1[key], dict) or isinstance(dict2[key], dict):
             dicts_are_equal = dicts_are_equal and compare_dictionaries(dict1[key], dict2[key])
         else:
             dicts_are_equal = dicts_are_equal and all(atleast_1d(dict1[key] == dict2[key]))

     return dicts_are_equal
```

Comment: If you use `not isinstance(dict1, dict)` instead of `type(dict1) is not dict`, this will work on other classes based on `dict. Also, instead of `(dict1[key] == dict2[key])`, you can do `all(atleast_1d(dict1[key] == dict2[key]))` to handle arrays at least.

Comment: +1, but you could break out of your `for loop` as soon as your `dicts_are_equal` becomes false. There's no need to continue any further.

Comment: I was suprised myself but it seems I can just compare nested dicts out of the box with == (using python3.8). ```>>> dict2 = {"a": {"a": {"a": "b"}}}
>>> dict1 = {"a": {"a": {"a": "b"}}}
>>> dict1 == dict2
True
>>> dict1 = {"a": {"a": {"a": "a"}}}
>>> dict1 == dict2
False```

Answer (score 9):

The function is fine IMO, clear and intuitive. But just to give you (another) answer, here is my go:

```
def compare_dict(dict1, dict2):
    for x1 in dict1.keys():
        z = dict1.get(x1) == dict2.get(x1)
        if not z:
            print('key', x1)
            print('value A', dict1.get(x1), '\nvalue B', dict2.get(x1))
            print('-----\n')
```

Can be useful for you or for anyone else..

EDIT:

I have created a recursive version of the one above.. Have not seen that in the other answers

```
def compare_dict(a, b):
    # Compared two dictionaries..
    # Posts things that are not equal..
    res_compare = []
    for k in set(list(a.keys()) + list(b.keys())):
        if isinstance(a[k], dict):
            z0 = compare_dict(a[k], b[k])
        else:
            z0 = a[k] == b[k]

        z0_bool = np.all(z0)
        res_compare.append(z0_bool)
        if not z0_bool:
            print(k, a[k], b[k])
    return np.all(res_compare)
```

Comment: Let's improve it so it works both ways. Line 2: "for x1 in set(dict1.keys()).union(dict2.keys()):"

Comment: Thanks @nkadwa, it does now

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way (and one of the more robust at that) to do a deep comparison of two dictionaries is to serialize them in JSON format, sorting the keys, and compare the string results:

```
import json
if json.dumps(x, sort_keys=True) == json.dumps(y, sort_keys=True):
   ... Do something ...
```

Comment: The most explicit one though not fastest.

Answer (score 8):

Yet another possibility, up to the last note of the OP, is to compare the hashes (`SHA` or `MD`) of the dicts dumped as JSON. The way hashes are constructed guarantee that if they are equal, the source strings are equal as well. This is very fast and mathematically sound.

```
import json
import hashlib

def hash_dict(d):
    return hashlib.sha1(json.dumps(d, sort_keys=True)).hexdigest()

x = dict(a=1, b=2)
y = dict(a=2, b=2)
z = dict(a=1, b=2)

print(hash_dict(x) == hash_dict(y))
print(hash_dict(x) == hash_dict(z))
```

Comment: That's completly wrong, just parsing the data into json is really slow. Then hashing that huge sring you just created is even worse. You should never do that

Comment: @Bruno: quoting the OP: *"Better not in speed, I am talking about code elegance"*

Comment: It's not elegant at all, it feels unsafe and it's overly complicated for a really simple problem

Comment: @Bruno: elegance is subjective. I can understand that you do not like it (and probably downvoted). This is not the same as "wrong".

Comment: This is a great answer. ``json.dumps(d, sort_keys=True)`` will give you canonical JSON so that you can be certain that both dict are equivalent. Also it depends what you are trying to achive. As soon as the value are not JSON serizalizable it will fail. For thus who say it is inefficient, have a look at the ujson project.

Comment: Once you dump the string to JSON, you can just compare it directly. Hashing the two strings is just meaningless extra complexity. (Also, this only works if the dict is JSON-able, which lots aren't.)

Answer (score 7):

To test if two dicts are equal in keys and values:

```
def dicts_equal(d1,d2):
    """ return True if all keys and values are the same """
    return all(k in d2 and d1[k] == d2[k]
               for k in d1) \
        and all(k in d1 and d1[k] == d2[k]
               for k in d2)
```

If you want to return the values which differ, write it differently:

```
def dict1_minus_d2(d1, d2):
    """ return the subset of d1 where the keys don't exist in d2 or
        the values in d2 are different, as a dict """
    return {k,v for k,v in d1.items() if k in d2 and v == d2[k]}
```

You would have to call it twice i.e

```
dict1_minus_d2(d1,d2).extend(dict1_minus_d2(d2,d1))
```

Answer (score 6):

## Code

```
def equal(a, b):
    type_a = type(a)
    type_b = type(b)
    
    if type_a != type_b:
        return False
    
    if isinstance(a, dict):
        if len(a) != len(b):
            return False
        for key in a:
            if key not in b:
                return False
            if not equal(a[key], b[key]):
                return False
        return True

    elif isinstance(a, list):
        if len(a) != len(b):
            return False
        while len(a):
            x = a.pop()
            index = indexof(x, b)
            if index == -1:
                return False
            del b[index]
        return True
        
    else:
        return a == b

def indexof(x, a):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if equal(x, a[i]):
            return i
    return -1
```

## Test

```
>>> a = {
    'number': 1,
    'list': ['one', 'two']
}
>>> b = {
    'list': ['two', 'one'],
    'number': 1
}
>>> equal(a, b)
True
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple compare with == should be enough nowadays (python 3.8). Even when you compare the same dicts in a different order (last example). The best thing is, you don't need a third-party package to accomplish this.

```
a = {'one': 'dog', 'two': 'cat', 'three': 'mouse'}
b = {'one': 'dog', 'two': 'cat', 'three': 'mouse'}

c = {'one': 'dog', 'two': 'cat', 'three': 'mouse'}
d = {'one': 'dog', 'two': 'cat', 'three': 'mouse', 'four': 'fish'}

e = {'one': 'cat', 'two': 'dog', 'three': 'mouse'}
f = {'one': 'dog', 'two': 'cat', 'three': 'mouse'}

g = {'two': 'cat', 'one': 'dog', 'three': 'mouse'}
h = {'one': 'dog', 'two': 'cat', 'three': 'mouse'}


print(a == b) # True
print(c == d) # False
print(e == f) # False
print(g == h) # True
```

Answer (score 5):

I am using this solution that works perfectly for me in Python 3

```py
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

...

    def deep_compare(self,left, right, level=0):
        if type(left) != type(right):
            log.info("Exit 1 - Different types")
            return False

        elif type(left) is dict:
            # Dict comparison
            for key in left:
                if key not in right:
                    log.info("Exit 2 - missing {} in right".format(key))
                    return False
                else:
                    if not deep_compare(left[str(key)], right[str(key)], level +1 ):
                        log.info("Exit 3 - different children")
                        return False
            return True
        elif type(left) is list:
            # List comparison
            for key in left:
                if key not in right:
                    log.info("Exit 4 - missing {} in right".format(key))
                    return False
                else:
                    if not deep_compare(left[left.index(key)], right[right.index(key)], level +1 ):
                        log.info("Exit 5 - different children")
                        return False
            return True
        else:
            # Other comparison
            return left == right

        return False
```

It compares dict, list and any other types that implements the "==" operator by themselves.
If you need to compare something else different, you need to add a new branch in the "if tree".

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

for python3:

```
data_set_a = dict_a.items()
data_set_b = dict_b.items()

difference_set = data_set_a ^ data_set_b
```

Answer (score 4):

In PyUnit there's a method which compares dictionaries beautifully. I tested it using the following two dictionaries, and it does exactly what you're looking for.

```
d1 = {1: "value1",
      2: [{"subKey1":"subValue1",
           "subKey2":"subValue2"}]}
d2 = {1: "value1",
      2: [{"subKey2":"subValue2",
           "subKey1": "subValue1"}]
      }


def assertDictEqual(self, d1, d2, msg=None):
        self.assertIsInstance(d1, dict, 'First argument is not a dictionary')
        self.assertIsInstance(d2, dict, 'Second argument is not a dictionary')

        if d1 != d2:
            standardMsg = '%s != %s' % (safe_repr(d1, True), safe_repr(d2, True))
            diff = ('\n' + '\n'.join(difflib.ndiff(
                           pprint.pformat(d1).splitlines(),
                           pprint.pformat(d2).splitlines())))
            standardMsg = self._truncateMessage(standardMsg, diff)
            self.fail(self._formatMessage(msg, standardMsg))
```

I'm not recommending importing `unittest` into your production code. My thought is the source in PyUnit could be re-tooled to run in production. It uses `pprint` which "pretty prints" the dictionaries. Seems pretty easy to adapt this code to be "production ready".

Comment: this one is especially useful for unit testing:
self.assertDictEqual(result, expected_result)

Answer (score 4):

Being late in my response is better than never!

Compare Not_Equal is more efficient than comparing Equal. As such two dicts are not equal if any key values in one dict is not found in the other dict. The code below takes into consideration that you maybe comparing default dict and thus uses get instead of **getitem** [].

Using a kind of random value as default in the get call equal to the key being retrieved - just in case the dicts has a None as value in one dict and that key does not exist in the other. Also the get != condition is checked before the not in condition for efficiency because you are doing the check on the keys and values from both sides at the same time.

```
def Dicts_Not_Equal(first,second):
    """ return True if both do not have same length or if any keys and values are not the same """
    if len(first) == len(second): 
        for k in first:
            if first.get(k) != second.get(k,k) or k not in second: return (True)
        for k in second:         
            if first.get(k,k) != second.get(k) or k not in first: return (True)
        return (False)   
    return (True)
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not just iterate through one dictionary and check the other in the process (assuming both dictionaries have the same keys)?

```
x = dict(a=1, b=2)
y = dict(a=2, b=2)

for key, val in x.items():
    if val == y[key]:
        print ('Ok', val, y[key])
    else:
        print ('Not', val, y[key])
```

Output:

```
Not 1 2
Ok 2 2
```

Answer (score 3):

see dictionary view objects:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict

This way you can subtract dictView2 from dictView1 and it will return a set of key/value pairs that are different in dictView2:

```
original = {'one':1,'two':2,'ACTION':'ADD'}
originalView=original.viewitems()
updatedDict = {'one':1,'two':2,'ACTION':'REPLACE'}
updatedDictView=updatedDict.viewitems()
delta=original | updatedDict
print delta
>>set([('ACTION', 'REPLACE')])
```

You can intersect, union, difference (shown above), symmetric difference these dictionary view objects.
Better? Faster? - not sure, but part of the standard library - which makes it a big plus for portability

Answer (score 3):

Below code will help you to compare list of dict in python

```
def compate_generic_types(object1, object2):
    if isinstance(object1, str) and isinstance(object2, str):
        return object1 == object2
    elif isinstance(object1, unicode) and isinstance(object2, unicode):
        return object1 == object2
    elif isinstance(object1, bool) and isinstance(object2, bool):
        return object1 == object2
    elif isinstance(object1, int) and isinstance(object2, int):
        return object1 == object2
    elif isinstance(object1, float) and isinstance(object2, float):
        return object1 == object2
    elif isinstance(object1, float) and isinstance(object2, int):
        return object1 == float(object2)
    elif isinstance(object1, int) and isinstance(object2, float):
        return float(object1) == object2

    return True

def deep_list_compare(object1, object2):
    retval = True
    count = len(object1)
    object1 = sorted(object1)
    object2 = sorted(object2)
    for x in range(count):
        if isinstance(object1[x], dict) and isinstance(object2[x], dict):
            retval = deep_dict_compare(object1[x], object2[x])
            if retval is False:
                print "Unable to match [{0}] element in list".format(x)
                return False
        elif isinstance(object1[x], list) and isinstance(object2[x], list):
            retval = deep_list_compare(object1[x], object2[x])
            if retval is False:
                print "Unable to match [{0}] element in list".format(x)
                return False
        else:
            retval = compate_generic_types(object1[x], object2[x])
            if retval is False:
                print "Unable to match [{0}] element in list".format(x)
                return False

    return retval

def deep_dict_compare(object1, object2):
    retval = True

    if len(object1) != len(object2):
        return False

    for k in object1.iterkeys():
        obj1 = object1[k]
        obj2 = object2[k]
        if isinstance(obj1, list) and isinstance(obj2, list):
            retval = deep_list_compare(obj1, obj2)
            if retval is False:
                print "Unable to match [{0}]".format(k)
                return False

        elif isinstance(obj1, dict) and isinstance(obj2, dict):
            retval = deep_dict_compare(obj1, obj2)
            if retval is False:
                print "Unable to match [{0}]".format(k)
                return False
        else:
            retval = compate_generic_types(obj1, obj2)
            if retval is False:
                print "Unable to match [{0}]".format(k)
                return False

    return retval
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//s.tk/meta/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer, use a recursize way:

```
def dict_equals(da, db):
    if not isinstance(da, dict) or not isinstance(db, dict):
        return False
    if len(da) != len(db):
        return False
    for da_key in da:
        if da_key not in db:
            return False
        if not isinstance(db[da_key], type(da[da_key])):
            return False
        if isinstance(da[da_key], dict):
            res = dict_equals(da[da_key], db[da_key])
            if res is False:
                return False
        elif da[da_key] != db[da_key]:
            return False
    return True

a = {1:{2:3, 'name': 'cc', "dd": {3:4, 21:"nm"}}}
b = {1:{2:3, 'name': 'cc', "dd": {3:4, 21:"nm"}}}
print dict_equals(a, b)
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> x = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
>>> x
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

>>> y = {'a':2,'b':4,'c':3}
>>> y
{'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 3}

METHOD 1:

>>> common_item = x.items()&y.items() #using union,x.item() 
>>> common_item
{('c', 3)}

METHOD 2:

 >>> for i in x.items():
        if i in y.items():
           print('true')
        else:
           print('false')


false
false
true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> hash_1
{'a': 'foo', 'b': 'bar'}
>>> hash_2
{'a': 'foo', 'b': 'bar'}
>>> set_1 = set (hash_1.iteritems())
>>> set_1
set([('a', 'foo'), ('b', 'bar')])
>>> set_2 = set (hash_2.iteritems())
>>> set_2
set([('a', 'foo'), ('b', 'bar')])
>>> len (set_1.difference(set_2))
0
>>> if (len(set_1.difference(set_2)) | len(set_2.difference(set_1))) == False:
...    print "The two hashes match."
...
The two hashes match.
>>> hash_2['c'] = 'baz'
>>> hash_2
{'a': 'foo', 'c': 'baz', 'b': 'bar'}
>>> if (len(set_1.difference(set_2)) | len(set_2.difference(set_1))) == False:
...     print "The two hashes match."
...
>>>
>>> hash_2.pop('c')
'baz'
```

Here's another option:

```
>>> id(hash_1)
140640738806240
>>> id(hash_2)
140640738994848
```

So as you see the two id's are different. But the [rich comparison operators](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) seem to do the trick:

```
>>> hash_1 == hash_2
True
>>>
>>> hash_2
{'a': 'foo', 'b': 'bar'}
>>> set_2 = set (hash_2.iteritems())
>>> if (len(set_1.difference(set_2)) | len(set_2.difference(set_1))) == False:
...     print "The two hashes match."
...
The two hashes match.
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.6, It can be done as:-

```
if (len(dict_1)==len(dict_2): 
  for i in dict_1.items():
        ret=bool(i in dict_2.items())
```

ret variable will be true if all the items of dict_1 in present in dict_2

Answer (score 0):

You can find that out by writing your own function in the following way.

```
class Solution:
    def find_if_dict_equal(self,dict1,dict2):
        dict1_keys=list(dict1.keys())
        dict2_keys=list(dict2.keys())
        if len(dict1_keys)!=len(dict2_keys):
            return False
        for i in dict1_keys:
            if i not in dict2 or dict2[i]!=dict1[i]:
                return False
        return True
        
    def findAnagrams(self, s, p):
        if len(s)<len(p):
            return []
        p_dict={}
        for i in p:
            if i not in p_dict:
                p_dict[i]=0
            p_dict[i]+=1
        s_dict={}
        final_list=[]
        for i in s[:len(p)]:
            if i not in s_dict:
                s_dict[i]=0
            s_dict[i]+=1
        if self.find_if_dict_equal(s_dict,p_dict):
            final_list.append(0)
        for i in range(len(p),len(s)):
            element_to_add=s[i]
            element_to_remove=s[i-len(p)]
            if element_to_add not in s_dict:
                s_dict[element_to_add]=0
            s_dict[element_to_add]+=1
            s_dict[element_to_remove]-=1
            if s_dict[element_to_remove]==0:
                del s_dict[element_to_remove]
            if self.find_if_dict_equal(s_dict,p_dict):
                final_list.append(i-len(p)+1)
        return final_list
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have a default/template dictionry that I want to update its values from a second given dictionary. Thus the update will happen on keys that exist in the default dictionary and if the related value is compatible with the default key/value type.

Somehow this is similar to the question above.

I wrote this solution:

**CODE**

```
def compDict(gDict, dDict):

    gDictKeys = list(gDict.keys())
    
    for gDictKey in gDictKeys: 
        try:
            dDict[gDictKey]
        except KeyError:
            # Do the operation you wanted to do for "key not present in dict".
            print(f'\nkey \'{gDictKey}\' does not exist! Dictionary key/value no set !!!\n')
        else:
            # check on type
            if type(gDict[gDictKey]) == type(dDict[gDictKey]):
                if type(dDict[gDictKey])==dict:
                    compDict(gDict[gDictKey],dDict[gDictKey])
                else:
                    dDict[gDictKey] = gDict[gDictKey]
                    print('\n',dDict, 'update successful !!!\n')
            else:
               print(f'\nValue \'{gDict[gDictKey]}\' for \'{gDictKey}\' not a compatible data type !!!\n')
            

# default dictionary
dDict = {'A':str(),
        'B':{'Ba':int(),'Bb':float()},
        'C':list(),
        }

# given dictionary
gDict = {'A':1234, 'a':'addio', 'C':['HELLO'], 'B':{'Ba':3,'Bb':'wrong'}}

compDict(gDict, dDict)

print('Updated default dictionry: ',dDict)
```

**OUTPUT**

Value '1234' for 'A' not a compatible data type !!!

key 'a' does not exist! Dictionary key/value no set !!!

{'A': '', 'B': {'Ba': 0, 'Bb': 0.0}, 'C': ['HELLO']} update successful !!!

{'Ba': 3, 'Bb': 0.0} update successful !!!

Value 'wrong' for 'Bb' not a compatible data type !!!

Updated default dictionry:  {'A': '', 'B': {'Ba': 3, 'Bb': 0.0}, 'C': ['HELLO']}

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```py
dict1 = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
dict2 = {"a": 2, "b": 2}

for key, value1 in dict1.items():
    value2 = dict2[key]
    if value1 == value2:
        print('Values match:', value1, value2)
    else:
        print('Values do not match:', value1, value2)
```

Output:

```
Values do not match: 1 2
Values match: 2 2
```

Here, `dict1` and `dict2` are being compared by iterating through the keys and checking the values for corresponding keys.

Answer (score -7):

```
import json

if json.dumps(dict1) == json.dumps(dict2):
    print("Equal")
```

Comment: This may not do what was exactly requested, and pulls in the json std lib, but it does work ( as `json.dumps` is deterministic with the default settings ).