# Comparing two Dictionaries and Print the Common

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, conditional-statements

I have two tab separated files with multiple columns.  I used 2 dictionaries, to store specific column of interest.

```
import csv
dic1={}
dic2={}
with open("Table1.tsv") as samplefile:
    reader = csv.reader(samplefile, delimiter="\t")
    columns = zip(*reader)
    for column in columns:
        A, B, C, D = columns

with open("Table2.tsv") as samplefile1:
     reader = csv.reader(samplefile1, delimiter="\t")
     columns = zip(*reader)
     for column1 in columns:
        A1, B1, C1 = columns

dic1['PMID'] = A  # the first dictionary storing the data of column "A"
dic2['PMID'] = A1 # the second dictionary storing the data of column "A1"

# statement to compare the data in dic1[PMID] with dic2['PMID'] and print the common
```

**Problem:** What is the proper logic /or conditional statement to use to compare the two dictionaries and print the common data in both.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing two dictionaries in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527942/comparing-two-dictionaries-in-python)

Comment: If I correctly understand your question, what you really want to compare are the 2 **lists** `A` (first column of first csv) and `A1` (first column or second csv). Is that true ?

Comment: Exactly thats my goal

Comment: Do you have any clue how to compare the two columns? @SergeBallesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **set intersection** as:

```
>>> d1={'a':2,'b':3,'c':4,'d':5}
>>> d2={'a':2,'f':3,'c':4,'b':5,'q':17}
>>> dict(set(d1.items()) & set(d2.items()))
{'a': 2, 'c': 4}
```

For your specific problem, this is the code:

```
>>> dic1={}
>>> dic2={}
>>> dic1['PMID']=[1,2,34,2,3,4,5,6,7,3,5,16]
>>> dic2['PMID']=[2,34,1,3,4,15,6,17,31,34,16]
>>> common=list(set(dic1['PMID']) & set(dic2['PMID']))
>>> common
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 34, 16]
```

Comment: Your feedback is valuable ... But I am not sure how to use `dict` and `set` for `dic1['PMID'] = A` and `dic2['PMID'] = A1` to print the common in both.  Could you show me how to apply your example in this case? @bhat irshad

Comment: Thank you a lot ... I really appreciate your input :)