# Python: Compare two identical dictionaries by key, value

Tags: python, dictionary, matching

I want to compare the length of the two dictionaries as well as each key,value pair in each dictionary. I also need to be able to print out if there is no match when looking for it.

My current code seems to pass on the length criteria but fails when trying to match elements:

```
assert_that(len(model_dict), len(server_dict))
    for x in model_dict:
        if x not in server_dict and model_dict[x] != server_dict[x]:
            print(x, model_dict[x])
```

server_dict example of one entry in dictionary:

> {2847001: [[[-94.8, 28], [-95.4, 28], [-96, 28], [-96.5, 28.1],
>   [-96.667, 28.133], [-97, 28.2], [-97.6, 28.3], [-98.3, 28.4], [-98.9,
>   28.6], [-99.4, 29], [-99.8, 29.5], [-100, 30], [-100.1, 30.5], [-100.2, 31]]]}

model_dict example of one entry in dictionary:

> {2847001: [[-94.8, 28], [-95.4, 28], [-96, 28], [-96.5, 28.1],
>   [-96.667, 28.133], [-97, 28.2], [-97.6, 28.3], [-98.3, 28.4], [-98.9,
>   28.6], [-99.4, 29], [-99.8, 29.5], [-100, 30], [-100.1, 30.5], [-100.2, 31]]}

Comment: Could you give some examples of failing input - what did you expect, and what happens instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two dictionaries in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527942/comparing-two-dictionaries-in-python)

Comment: Try looking up the `set` data structure in python, since that do a lot of the work for you in this particular problem.

Comment: sorry had to go afk, @jonrsharpe - updated qn to reflect example of entries in each dictionary.

Comment: should the values be identical?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - yes, the only problem I can really see is the server_dict have an additional array, i.e. [[[-94.8, 28] ... ]]] vs [[-94.8, 28] ... ]]. Any ideas how to get rid of it?

Comment: One key is a string and the other an int also no?

Comment: yea i fixed that, sorry updated qn, strings should be gone.

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: trying to compare 2 dictionaries one I got from the server from a json, the other read in from a csv file. they should be identical, and any entries which don't match/cannot be found, should be printed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check each key and value you can use dict.items and dict.get with a default value:

```
for k,v  in model_dict.items():
       if server_dict.get(k,object()) != v:
            print(k,v)
```

If you just wanted any keys that are not the same from either dict you could get the symmetric difference:

```
unique = model_dict.keys() ^ server_dict # viewkeys() python2
```

Comment: that works as intended, but how do I get rid of the extra braces [] in the values of server_dict? I think that's why the damn thing won't match :/

Comment: @user4659009, you would have to restructure the dict but how did you end up with the extra nesting, did you create each structure or from an outside source?

Comment: Outside source - json from a rest endpoint. Would doing the following line instead work - braces around the v? `if server_dict.get(k,object()) != [v]:`

Comment: @user4659009, yep but ideally sorting out the root of the problem would be best, wrapping v in a list could potentially cause some bugs

Comment: Mmm. `for x in context.response.result['features']:
        for y in x['geometry']['coordinates']:
            server_response_coordinate_dict.setdefault(x['properties']['event_id'], []).append(y)` Tried a number of things, but can't get it to work as intended.

Comment: stick the full  code in pastebin, pretty sure I know what is happening

Answer (score 2):

The mistake seems to be in the usage of `and` in the condition:

```
x not in server_dict and model_dict[x] != server_dict[x]
```

If the first condition passes, the second one makes no sense. Try `or` instead:

```
x not in server_dict or model_dict[x] != server_dict[x]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `or`, not `and`. If it's is not in `server_dict`, you don't want to check it there.

Answer (score 0):

you're overdoing it, that is the error. when you write this

```
for x in model_dict:
    if x not in server_dict and model_dict[x] != server_dict[x]:
        print(x, model_dict[x])
```

For each key in `model_dict`, you're checking whether the same key is not found in `server_dict` which itself is enough. what you're doing after the `and` is not at all necessary, and not correct, because you're trying to match the key's value in `model_dict` to a non-existent key's value in `server_dict`.

Just do this:

```
{x: model_dict(x) for x in model_dict if x not in server_dict}
```

Comment: I should have been clearer, these two dictionaries are meant to be identical, hence the assumption about finding the key in both of them