# Get non-matching data when comparing python dicts and store them

Tags: python

I have 2 python dicts... I'm currently checking if they match. But how can I get the non-matched keys and values from items and store them?

```
data1 = {'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Doe', 'username': 'johndoe'} 
data2 = {'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Doe', 'username': 'johohoho'}

for (key, value) in set(data1.items()) & set(data2.items()):
        print(key, value) 
# this returns only matching data. how can i grab the non matched?
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: You should read the other answers of the dupe here [Comparing two dictionaries in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4527942) also, Not just the first :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't see any examples of deduping @BhargavRao

Comment: xor should do ? `^`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xor for non matching entries just like you are catching matched entries:

```
>>> for (key, value) in set(data1.items()) ^ set(data2.items()):
...         print(key, value) 
... 
('username', 'johndoe')
('username', 'johohoho')
```

Note: this won't work for nested dictionaries