# match entire element in a list of dictionaries python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries and want to find a match for the element of this list(element being an entire dictionary). Not sure how to do this in Python.

Here is what I need:

```
list_of_dict = [ {a : 2, b : 3, c : 5}, {a : 4, b : 5, c : 5}, {a : 3, b : 4, c : 4} ]

dict_to_match = {a : 4, b : 5, c : 5}
```

so with above input the `dict_to_match` should match the second element in list `list_of_dict`

Can some one help with a good solution for this problem?

Comment: `if dict_to_match in list_of_dict:`

Comment: If you just want to know how to compare 2 dicts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527942/comparing-two-dictionaries-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Not so different from comparing an integer or a string:

```
list_of_dict = [ {'a' : 2, 'b' : 3, 'c' : 5}, {'a' : 4, 'b' : 5, 'c' : 5}, {'a' : 3, 'b' : 4, 'c' : 4} ]

dict_to_match = {'a' : 4, 'b' : 5, 'c' : 5}

if dict_to_match in list_of_dict:
    print("a match found at index", list_of_dict.index(dict_to_match))
else:
    print("not match found")
```

Suggested by [Patrick Haugh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6779307/patrick-haugh) and [ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger).

Comment: Is there some reason not to use `in` ?

Answer (score 0):

Using a loop and the equals operator:

```
list_of_dict = [ {a : 2, b : 3, c : 5}, {a : 4, b : 5, c : 5}, {a : 3, b : 4, c : 4} ]
dict_to_match = {a : 4, b : 5, c : 5}
for i, d in enumerate(list_of_dict):
    if d == dict_to_match:
        print 'matching element at position %d' % i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if dict_to_match in list_of_dict:
    print "a match found"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_dict = [ {'a' : 2, 'b' : 3, 'c' : 5}, {'a' : 4, 'b' : 5, 'c' : 5}, {'a' : 3, 'b' : 4, 'c' : 4} ]

dict_to_match = {'a' : 4, 'b' : 5, 'c' : 5}

for each in list_of_dict:
   if each == dict_to_match:
     print each, dict_to_match
```

I have tested this code and it works, I hope it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

Python < 3:

```
filter(lambda x: x == dict_to_match, list_of_dict)[0]
```

Python 3 :

```
list(filter(lambda x: x == dict_to_match, list_of_dict))[0]
```

Comment: If you need a `lambda` to use `filter`, don't use `filter`. It's going to be slower than the equivalent list comprehension or generator expression (and the listcomp/genexpr will have identical semantics on both Py2 and Py3) that omits the `lambda`: `[d for d in list_of_dict if d == dict_to_match]`. Of course, in this case, you only want one of them, and you don't actually need to return it, so it's sort of pointless regardless.