# Comparing two Json tree in Python

Tags: python, json

I have this kind of Json tree for folder structure. Is there any way to compare it with same kind of Json tree to get differences (file missing or different file properties (date,crc,..)) and return this as a list with names of different/missing files.

```
{
      "testfolder": {
        "children": {
          "content.json": {
            "last_modified_timestamp": 1485902084.0222416, 
            "created_timestamp": 1485193414.5027652, 
            "crc": "7c71cf7ff765ddd78fffcac2eed56ae2", 
            "type": "file", 
            "size": 961
          }, 
          "config.json": {
            "last_modified_timestamp": 1484831126.4821935, 
            "created_timestamp": 1484830625.6165457, 
            "crc": "bff5d42e18df483841aa10df8b38cdd4", 
            "type": "file", 
            "size": 132
          }
        }
      },  
      "__init__.py": {
        "last_modified_timestamp": 1481651800.7150106, 
        "created_timestamp": 1481651800.7150106, 
        "crc": "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e", 
        "type": "file", 
        "size": 0
      }, 
      "test.json": {
        "last_modified_timestamp": 1486126931.2528062, 
        "created_timestamp": 1486126732.7074502, 
        "crc": "8a30d9b3834ef46ad3b996edb06c72bf", 
        "type": "file", 
        "size": 1675
      }, 
      "test": {
        "children": {
          "test.txt.txt": {
            "last_modified_timestamp": 1486126927.9266162, 
            "created_timestamp": 1486126865.9750726, 
            "crc": "b5301fdbf2ba41520b255a651c7017b1", 
            "type": "file", 
            "size": 5
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: load both in dictionaries and then use the numerous answers on comparing dicts, like that one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527942/comparing-two-dictionaries-in-python

Comment: I have tried with recursion that returns list of files with full paths and than just difference between two lists but that solved only missing files not different files.

Answer (score 0):

```
def jsondiff(local,online,path='',todo=[]):
  for key in local.keys():
      if not online.has_key(key):
          if local[key].has_key('children'):
              todo = todo + json_path_print(local[key]["children"],path+key+"/")
          else:
              todo.append(path+key)
      else:
          if local[key].has_key('children'):
              todo=todo+jsondiff(local[key]["children"],online[key]["children"],path+key+"/")
          else:
              if local[key]["last_modified_timestamp"]>online[key]["last_modified_timestamp"]:
                  todo.append(path + key)
  return todo
```

Solved it if anyone need solution