# Python3: How to compare data of two dictionaries which is nested and dynamic in nature?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I am trying to find a way to compare two dictionaries without any library but the data is nested and keys are not ordered too.The data is dynamic in nature meaning the the keys in dictionary will change and nesting also.
I am not able to parse the dictionary if the nesting is not fixed.

Example data:

```
source_data = {
    "name":"Kaleigh", "username":"Kaleigh60", "email":"Kaleigh6047@gmail.com",
    "address":{
        "street":"MyahCourse","suite":"Apt.657","city":"Boyerberg","zipcode":"66413-8920",
        "geo":{"lat":"-44.6203","lng":"16.7454"}
    },
    "website":"megane.biz",
    "friends":[
        {"name":"Little-Reinger","catchPhrase":"Enhancedregionalemulation"},
        {"name":"Big-Reinger","catchPhrase":"emulation"}
    ],
    "Numbers":[1,2,3,4]
}

destination_data = {
    "name":"Kaligh", "username": "Kaleigh60", "email": "Kaleigh6047@gmail.com",
    "address":{
        "street":"GoldCourse", "suite":"Apt.657", "city":"Boyerberg",
        "zipcode":"66413-8920",
        "geo":{"lat":"-44.6203","lng":"16.7454"}
    },
    "website":"megane.biz",
    "friends":[
        {"name":"Reinger", "catchPhrase":"Enhancedregionalemulation"},
        {"name":"Big-Reinger","catchPhrase":"emulation"}
    ],
    "Numbers":[4,2,1,5]
}
```

I am not able to understand how can I parse the and compare the dictionary?
Expected Output: keys whose value is different and values as list `[srcvalue,destvalue]` e.g.

```
{
    "friends[1].name": ["Big-Reinger", "Bigger-Reinger"],
    "name":["Kaleigh","Kaligh"],
    "Numbers[2]":[3,1],
    "Numbers[3]":[4,5],
    "friends[0].name":["Little-Reinger","Reinger"],
    "Numbers[0]":[1,4],
    "address.street":["MyahCourse","GoldCourse"]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How exactly do you want to compare the dictionaries? What is your desired output?

Comment: what comparisons are we searching for, desired output

Comment: Use `==`. Dictionaries don't care about order and until recent versions, weren't meant to be ordered.

Comment: Unless you can show what you're actually doing that isn't working, your question is extremely unclear, and I'm voting to close.

Comment: @vash_the_stampede I have updated the problem with desired output too.Basically i want to match key and their value and return which are not same.

Comment: @panktijk have updated question with desired output.Please take a look.

Comment: @U9-Forward I got a head start on you, but this has your name written all over it

Answer (score 0):

The built-in equality operator for dict already compares nested dict values recursively.

```
>>> a={1:2,3:4,2:{2:4}}
>>> b={3:4,2:{2:4},1:2}
>>> a==b
True
>>> b={3:4,2:{2:3},1:2}
>>> a==b
False
>>>
```

Comment: thanks for answering but i want that it also return the unmatched key value pair

Answer (score -1):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527942/comparing-two-dictionaries-in-python)

You can compare two dictionaries based on values like this:

```
for x_values, y_values in zip(source_data.iteritems(), destination_data.iteritems()):
        if x_values == y_values:
            # Matched
        else:
            # Not Matched
```

Comment: This would fail in Python 3, which the question is specifically asking about.