# Remove duplicates from a list of alphanumeric filenames

Tags: python, sorting, unix, duplicates, alphanumeric

I have a list of alphanumeric filenames, as follows:

```
['build999.100', 'build999.0', 'buil998.100', 
 'build997.100', 'build996.100', 'build996.0']
```

I want to get a list removing the duplicates of the suffix post '.', i.e. I want my list to be

```
['build999.100', 'buil998.100', 'build997.100', 'build996.100']
```

The suffix after `'.'` does not matter, I just need to remove the duplicates on the basis of `999, 998` etc.

I am looking for implementations in either Python or Unix.

Comment: Does it matter which minor number build you keep? In your example you keep build999.100 over build999.0, any particular reason for 100 over 0? Or does it not matter?

Comment: It does not matter. I just need one instance of them.

Answer (score 1):

A simple & efficient way to do this is to use a dictionary, with the prefix as the key, since the keys of a dict are unique.

```
data = ['build999.100', 'build999.0', 'buil998.100', 'build997.100', 'build996.100', 'build996.0']
d = {s.split('.')[0]: s for s in data}
out = list(d.values())
```

Comment: WOW this using a dictionary here abusing the fact can only have on key this is wonderful, tagging you in a question I want you to solve

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52473178/python3-how-to-compare-data-of-two-dictionaries-which-is-nested-and-dynamic-in going to my friends you better have solved this before I return

Comment: @vash_the_stampede Sorry, I'm on my phone. And I need to get some sleep soon.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions:

```
import re
a = ['build999.100', 'build999.0', 'buil998.100', 
    'build997.100', 'build996.100', 'build996.0']
list(set(map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\..*$', '.100', x), a)))
```

or

```
list(set([re.sub(r'\..*$', '.100', x) for x in a]))
```

Result is

```
>> ['build996.100', 'build999.100', 'buil998.100', 'build997.100']
```