# How to find common occurrences of dictionary in a list of list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of list of dictionaries and I want to find the common dictionaries between the two list.

Eg:

```
dict_list = [[{'1' : 1,'2' : 2, '3' :3}, {'6' : 6,'5' : 5, '4' : 4}],  
             [{'1' : 1,'2' : 2, '3' :3}, {'7' : 7,'8' : 8, '9' : 9}]]
```

The result should be `[{'1' : 1,'2' : 2, '3' :3}]`

I tried using set intersections but dictionaries are unhashable in python.

How to solve this?

Comment: `[dict(k) for k,v in  Counter(tuple(x.items()) for x in  chain.from_iterable(dict_list)).items() if v > 1]
`

Comment: @Chris_Rands I didn't see your solution at all when I posted mine. Do you want me to remove it?

Comment: @RoadRunner no don't remove it, people do have the same idea sometimes, thanks for asking though :)

Comment: after converting a list of dict to list of tuple, he can use set.intersection too, I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *list comprehension* could work here:

```
>>> [x for x in dict_list[0] if x in dict_list[1]]
[{'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3}]
```

But this is not a very general solution, since it assumes only two nested lists are exististent.

A more general solution would be to count the occurences with [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), and storing the dictionary `items()` with hashable/immutable types such as [`frozenset()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-frozenset) or [`tuple()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-tuple). Then all you need to do is filter the occurences that count *more* than 1.

**Example:**

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> [dict(k) for k, v in Counter(frozenset(x.items()) for x in chain.from_iterable(dict_list)).items() if v > 1]
[{'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3}]
```

Which is very similar to the approach [@Chris_Rands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53298540/how-to-find-common-occurrences-of-dictionary-in-a-list-of-list-of-dictionaries/53298618#comment93477994_53298540) posted in the comments.

Comment: The main point here is that even though dictionaries are not hashable they are comparable. [More about comparing dictionaries in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527942/comparing-two-dictionaries-in-python).