# Getting Dict Value from same source at different times and comparing them

Tags: python, dictionary, ceph

I am working on a ceph mgr plugin. I have a dict that I get from `self.get('health')`. The keys and values in the dict changes depending on the health of the system.

What I want to achieve is to write a function in python that gets the value of `self.get('health')` every 1 minute and compare it with the previous value i.e. `oldDictValue` compared to `newDictValue` where `newDictValue` is the dict value gotten after 1 minute.

`oldDictValue` and `newDictValue` are variables holding values from `self.get('health')` at different times.

Comment: I think you can combine those two posts to solve your problem: [interval timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds-in-python) and [comparing 2 dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527942/comparing-two-dictionaries-in-python)

Comment: @HaBom this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527942/comparing-two-dictionaries-in-python] will not quite work because the dict lenght will be different if there's a change in status

Comment: Yeah, there are so many ways to compare 2 dictionaries in that post, but they're just the ideas. Can you provide a sample of dictionaries?

Comment: Can you put it in the question for easier understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposed pseudo code for what I wish to achieve. I am finding it difficult to covert this to a working solution

````
```  
   fun diff_health(old_health, new_health):
       old = {}
       new = {}
       updated = {}
      for code, item in new_health['checks'].iteritems():
          if code not in old_health['checks']:
              # it's a new alert
              new[code] = item
          else:
             old_item = old_health['checks'][code]
        if item['severity'] != old_item['severity'] or item['summary']['message']    != old_item['usmmary']['message']:
            # changed
            updated[code] = item
       for code, item in old_health['checks'].iteritems():
           if code not in new_health['checks']:
             # health alert has resolved
        ...
      return old, new, updated
```
````

new_health and old_health are values from `self.get('heatth')` at diffrent times