# Python: Turn my dictionary into literal string

Tags: python, string, dictionary, printing

I have an issue transforming my current variable(which is a dictionary) into a literal string. I have a dictionary variable such as :

```
tmp = {"e":"abc' efg"}
```

And I want to convert `tmp` into a string, such as

```
'''{"e":"abc' efg"}'''
```

However, when I use `str(tmp)`, I get

```
'{\'e\': "abc\' efg"}'
```

which I do not want to have escape symbol for the string.

How would I get a value such that

```
'''{"e":"abc' efg"}'''
```

In another word, I am looking forward an operation(op) such that

`op(tmp)==tmp1` is `true`, where `tmp = {"e":"abc' efg"}, tmp1='''{"e":"abc' efg"}'''` .

Comment: Are all of your values JSON-serializable? How about `json.dumps(tmp)`?

Comment: The backslashes aren't actually in the string, they're just how a string containing backslashes is displayed.

Comment: If you do `print(str(tmp))` you won't see the backslashes.

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks a lot! This is what I am looking for. By the way,
Suppose 
tmp = {"e":"abc' efg"}
tmp1 = '''{"e":"abc' efg"}'''
What is the operation on tmp so that op(tmp)==tmp1 is True? Currently, what I have check is that str(tmp)==tmp1 or json.dumps(tmp)==tmp1 is False.

Comment: @Barmar. Hello, Thank you for your comments. It is helping me a lot.. Actually, what I am looking for is that
Suppose 
tmp = {"e":"abc' efg"}
tmp1 = '''{"e":"abc' efg"}'''
What is the operation on tmp so that op(tmp)==tmp1 is True? Currently, str(tmp)==tmp1 or json.dumps(tmp)==tmp1 is False.

Comment: The answer is that you shouldn't use string comparisons. You should decode the string with `json.loads()` or `ast.literal_eval()` and then compare the data.

Comment: There are too many different ways to convert data to a string, such as different amounts of whitespace.

Comment: If you're really trying to check if two dicts are equal, stringifying them is likely not the best way to go. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527942/comparing-two-dictionaries-and-checking-how-many-key-value-pairs-are-equal

Comment: @Barmar Thanks a lot. cannot make a day with your unreserved help.

Comment: @ggorlen wish I could thank you in person.