# How do I know if there are any 'equal values' in two or more dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there any pythonic way to find out this?

```
dic1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'points': 100}
dic2 = {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'points': 100}

---> Ture  # because points in dic1 and dic2 are equal
```

and also

```
dic1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'points': 200}
dic2 = {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'points': 100}

---> False # because points in dic1 and dic2 are not equal
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a way with this post :
[Comparing two dictionaries and checking how many (key, value) pairs are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527942/comparing-two-dictionaries-and-checking-how-many-key-value-pairs-are-equal)

you'll have to check the length of :

```
shared_items = {k: dic1[k] for k in dic1 if k in dic2 and dic1[k] == dic2[k]}
print len(shared_items)
```

Change it a little to avoid error if there is not the same keys in both dicts