# Compare the ordering of dictionaries

Tags: python, numpy

I have two dictionaries which order represented by their values.

```
d1= {570.44: 2, 305.21: 1, 271.94: 0, 463.20: 3, 556.60: 4, 596.27: 5}

d2= {570.44: 537.5, 596.27: 767.0, 556.60: 644.5, 271.94: 285.0, 305.21: 334.5, 463.20: 428.5}
```

I would like to compare *the order*, which is defined by the value.

For example, `570.44` won't be the same according to the values, in d1 it would be in the third position, while in d2 it will be in the fourth.

```
d1[570.44] <  d2[570.44]
```

As you can see, when I mean ***order*** I mean the order determined by the value of the keys, not by order of insertion etc.

How can I compare these two dictionaries?  (usually the comparisons are for equality like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527942/comparing-two-dictionaries-and-checking-how-many-key-value-pairs-are-equal) but I am interested in order

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. Do you mean that you want to know if a key exists in both dictionaries but in a different relative position?

Comment: Are you looking for `OrderedDict`?

Comment: @DarkKnight yes, I want to know if the keys are ordered in the same order, and if not, take some action

Comment: What do you consider equal? Both dictionaries have the same keys in the same order? Can one dictionary have keys that are not in the other dictionary and will they still be considered equal if the common keys are in the same order?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I am not evaluating equality (since the values of the keys are different). I am evaluating order.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Also, yes d2 can have less keys than d1, the thing is that the remaining are in the same order

Comment: @RaviJoshi I checked `OrderedDict` and it seems that is not what I want, since that only *preserves* the order of insertion.

Comment: @KansaiRobot can you check my update?

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you want to take only the relative order of common keys into account, you can create two lists of keys (sorted by their respective values), and filter out the keys that are not present in the other dictionary.

Then, comparing those two lists for equality should give you your result.

```
d1= {570.44: 2, 305.21: 1, 271.94: 0, 463.20: 3, 556.60: 4, 596.27: 5}
d2= {570.44: 537.5, 596.27: 767.0, 556.60: 644.5, 271.94: 285.0, 305.21: 334.5, 463.20: 428.5}

k1 = list(filter(lambda k: k in d2, sorted(d1, key=d1.get)))
k2 = list(filter(lambda k: k in d1, sorted(d2, key=d2.get)))

print("Same order") if (k1 == k2) else print("Different order")
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, this might be what you want. Simply sort the dictionaries by their value and compare the list of ordered keys.

```py
In [10]: d1_ordered = [k for k, _ in sorted(d1.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])]    

In [11]: d2_ordered = [k for k, _ in sorted(d2.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])]    

In [12]: d1_ordered                                                             
Out[12]: [271.94, 305.21, 570.44, 463.2, 556.6, 596.27]

In [13]: d2_ordered                                                             
Out[13]: [271.94, 305.21, 463.2, 570.44, 556.6, 596.27]


In [14]: for idx, d1_k in enumerate(d1_ordered): 
    ...:     if d1_k not in d2_ordered: 
    ...:         print(f"Key {d1_k} not exists in d2") 
    ...:         continue 
    ...:     if idx != d2_ordered.index(d1_k): 
    ...:         print(f"Key {d1_k} is in different order in these dicts") 
    ...:                                                                        
Key 570.44 is in different order in these dicts
Key 463.2 is in different order in these dicts
```

Answer (score 0):

*I want to know if the keys are ordered in the same order, and if not, take some action ; The order is given by the values of the keys*

Then, you can simply do: `sorted(d1, key=d1.get) == sorted(d2, key=d2.get)`

output: `False`

edit. If the dictionaries have different lengths and you only want to compare the first common items:

```
d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 0}
d2 = {'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 2}

k1 = sorted(d1, key=d1.get)
k2 = sorted(d2, key=d2.get)
k1[:len(k2)] == k2[:len(k1)]
```

output: `True`

Comment: The order is given by the values of the keys

Comment: OK, I didn't get that point, let me fix it

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help:-

```
d1 = {570.44: 2, 305.21: 1, 271.94: 0, 463.20: 3, 556.60: 4, 596.27: 5}
d2 = {570.44: 537.5, 596.27: 767.0, 556.60: 644.5,
      271.94: 285.0, 305.21: 334.5, 463.20: 428.5}

d2_keys = list(d2.keys())

for i, k in enumerate(d1.keys()):
    try:
        if i == d2_keys.index(k):
            print(f'Key {k} is in same relative position')
        else:
            print(f'Key {k} is not in same relative position')
    except ValueError:
        pass # key in d1 doesn't exist in d2
```