# How to properly compare 2 JSON request response strings in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to compare 2 Python response strings and print out the differences, here is my code right now:

import requests
import json
import time

getFirst = requests.get("https://api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections?offset=0&limit=1")
liveRN = json.dumps(getFirst.json(), indent=4)

while True:
get = requests.get("https://api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections?offset=0&limit=1")
dataPretty = json.dumps(get.json(), indent=4)
data = get.json()

```
if get.status_code == 200:
    print("ok")
if dataPretty != data:
    for item in data:
        if str(item) not in liveRN:
            send = 1
            print(f"Found difference: {item}")

            symbol = item['symbol']
            img = item['image']
            name = item['name']
            description = item['description']

            print(symbol)
            print(img)
            print(name)
                         
        else:
            print("Didnt find")
else:
    print("No change")

time.sleep(15)
```

I only want to print the items when the two repsonses dont match but right now its printing the items I want even when the strings do match.

I tried to see add another if condition where if the 2 request response match it wont do anything and just pass but that didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sets` to find whether items of the dictionary are changed or not. I've used the compare code from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527942/comparing-two-dictionaries-and-checking-how-many-key-value-pairs-are-equal) but this is somewhat what you can use for your problem

```
import requests 
import time

def dict_compare(d1, d2):
    d1_keys = set(d1.keys())
    d2_keys = set(d2.keys())
    shared_keys = d1_keys.intersection(d2_keys)
    added = d1_keys - d2_keys
    removed = d2_keys - d1_keys
    modified = {o : (d1[o], d2[o]) for o in shared_keys if d1[o] != d2[o]}
    same = set(o for o in shared_keys if d1[o] == d2[o])
    return added, removed, modified, same

first = requests.get("https://api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections?offset=0&limit=1").json()[0]

while True: 
    get_second = requests.get("https://api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections?offset=0&limit=1")

    if get_second.status_code == 200:
        print("ok")

    second = get_second.json()[0]
    added, removed, modified, same = dict_compare(first, second)

    if len(added) > 0 or len(modified) > 0  or len(removed) > 0:
        print("added: ", added)
        print("modified: ", modified)
        print("removed: ", removed)
    else:
        print("No change")
        
    time.sleep(15)
```