# How to compare dictionaries and see what changed?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having 3 dictionaries in my python code :

1. `self.new_port_dict = {}`       # Dictionary to store the new ports
   from curr_host
2. `self.old_port_dict = {}`       # Dictionary to store the old ports from old_host
3. `self.results_ports_dict = {}`  # Holds the result of changed/newly added ports

The script needs to compare what port changed, I am almost there just unable to present help me out :

```
      def comp_ports(self,filename):
          try:
                f = open(filename)
                self.prev_report = pickle.load(f) # NmapReport

                for s in self.prev_report.hosts:
                    self.old_port_dict[s.address] = set()
                    for x in s.get_open_ports():
                        self.old_port_dict[s.address].add(x)

                for s in self.report.hosts:
                    self.new_port_dict[s.address] = set()
                    for x in s.get_open_ports():
                       self.new_port_dict[s.address].add(x)

                print "The following Host/ports were available in old scan : !!"
                print `self.old_port_dict`
                print "--------------------------------------------------------"
                print "The following Host/ports have been added in new scan:  !!"
                print `self.new_port_dict`
                for h in self.old_port_dict.keys():
                 self.results_ports_dict[h] = self.new_port_dict[h]- self.old_port_dict[h]
                 print "Result Change: for",h ,"->",self.results_ports_dict[h]         

 except Exception as l:
             print l
```

This gives a output as :

```
The following Host/ports were available in old scan : !!
{'172.16.0.41': set([(80, 'tcp'), (666, 'tcp')]), '172.16.0.163': set([(80, 'tcp'), (22, 'tcp')])}
--------------------------------------------------------
The following Host/ports have been added in new scan:  !!
{'172.16.0.41': set([(80, 'tcp'), (22, 'tcp')]), '172.16.0.163': set([(80, 'tcp'), (22, 'tcp')])}

Result Change: for 172.16.0.41 -> set([(22, 'tcp')])  From set([(80, 'tcp'), (666, 'tcp')])

Result Change: for 172.16.0.163 -> set([])  From set([(80, 'tcp'), (22, 'tcp')])
```

As you can clearly see , I have the resulting changed dictionary as well. I want to just print :

```
    For "host_name" , Port changed from "port_id" to "new_port_id" 

ex: For 172.16.0.41, Port changed from (666, 'tcp')  to  (22, 'tcp')
```

Comment: I think the end of your code is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your are not comparing the **dictionaries** but actually the values corresponding to the keys.

The basic ideas here are:

- A host must not always be present in past and present scans and hance the usage of `collections.defaultdict`, to ensure a straightforward comparison of values even in the absence of a host. Because a value for the *missing* key will be automatically generated (an empty `set`)
- Have 3 operations on the `set` of ports

  - `&` (intersection): to see which ports have remained constant across scans (same ports)
  - `old - new`: to see which ports were in the old scan but no longer in the new (deleted ports)
  - `new - old`: to see which ports are in the new scan but were not in the old (added ports)

There are several ways to move the code around to optimize, but I guess the point is much more clarity.

Hope it helps

```
import collections

scan0 = collections.defaultdict(set, {
    '172.16.0.41': set([(80, 'tcp'), (666, 'tcp')]),
    '172.16.0.163': set([(80, 'tcp'), (22, 'tcp')])
})

scan1 = collections.defaultdict(set, {
    '172.16.0.41': set([(80, 'tcp'), (22, 'tcp')]),
    '172.16.0.163': set([(80, 'tcp'), (22, 'tcp')])
})

hosts = sorted(set(scan0.keys() + scan1.keys()))


scan_same = dict()
scan_new = dict()
scan_del = dict()

for host in hosts:
    scan_same[host] = scan0[host] & scan1[host]
    scan_new[host] = scan1[host] - scan0[host]
    scan_del[host] = scan0[host] - scan1[host]

print()
print('-' * 10, 'Same')
for host, ports in scan_same.items():
    print(host, ':')
    for port in ports:
        print(':::', port[0], '/', port[1])
print()
print('*' * 10, 'Added')
for host, ports in scan_new.items():
    print(host, ':')
    for port in ports:
        print(':::', port[0], '/', port[1])

print()
print('=' * 10, 'Deleted')
for host, ports in scan_del.items():
    print(host, ':')
    for port in ports:
        print(':::', port[0], '/', port[1])
```

This will output:

```
---------- Same
172.16.0.163 :
::: 80 / tcp
::: 22 / tcp
172.16.0.41 :
::: 80 / tcp

*********** Added
172.16.0.163 :
172.16.0.41 :
::: 22 / tcp

========== Deleted
172.16.0.163 :
172.16.0.41 :
::: 666 / tcp
```

Comment: I like this :) kudos , will try and implement this also

Answer (score 2):

Based on Alex Martelli's answer on [Is there a better way to compare dictionary values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911273/is-there-a-better-way-to-compare-dictionary-values)

You can do this :

```
#eval the differences between the 2 dict:
diff_key=[key for key in old_port_dict if old_port_dict[key]!=new_port_dict[key]]
for key in diff_key:
    print "For %s, Port changed from %s to %s" %(key,old_port_dict[key],new_port_dict[key])
```

Comment: yeah, it pretty much gives me :

For 172.16.0.41, Port changed from set([(80, 'tcp'), (25, 'tcp')]) to set([(80, 'tcp'), (22, 'tcp')])

but i what if i wanna show only the changed port and not 80,tcp as it is not changed

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep another set like `old_port_dict_changed = self.old_port_dict[h] - self.new_port_dict[h]` now the changed ports from the `old_port_dict` are in `old_port_dict_changed` and the new ports which replaced the old ones are in `results_ports_dict`. Does that help?

Comment: Yep.. hmm yeah i can do that i guess

Comment: Good, so if it helped you, please like the answer.