# How to use collections.defaultdict, to ensure a straightforward comparison of values in Python

Tags: python, collections

Basically this is a code modification of a previous question i saw on stack-overflow & I found it interesting to pursue which deals with port scanning . In this code I am trying to compare 2 pickle files which hold the scan result of 2 scans performed one after another. I am interested in finding

3 operations on the set of ports

> ```
> & (intersection): to see which ports have remained constant across scans (same ports)
>
> old - new: to see which ports were in the old scan but no longer in the new (deleted ports)
>
> new - old: to see which ports are in the new scan but were not in the old (added ports)
> ```

```
def comp_ports(self,filename):
  try:
        f = open(filename)
        self.prev_report = pickle.load(f) # NmapReport

        for s in self.prev_report.hosts:
            self.old_port_dict[s.address] = collections.defaultdict(set())
            for x in s.get_open_ports():
                self.old_port_dict[s.address].add(x)

        for s in self.report.hosts:
            self.new_port_dict[s.address] = collections.defaultdict(set())
            for x in s.get_open_ports():
               self.new_port_dict[s.address].add(x)

        hosts = sorted(set(self.prev_report.hosts.keys() + self.report.hosts.keys()))

        for host in hosts:
                scan_same[host] = self.prev_report.hosts[host] & self.report.hosts[host]
                scan_new[host]  = self.report.hosts[host] - self.prev_report.hosts[host]
                scan_del[host]  = self.prev_report.hosts[host] - self.report.hosts[host]

        print()
        print('-' * 10, 'Same')
        for host, ports in scan_same.items():
            print(host, ':')
            for port in ports:
                 print(':::', port[0], '/', port[1])

        print()
        print('*' * 10, 'Added')
        for host, ports in scan_new.items():
            print(host, ':')
            for port in ports:
                  print(':::', port[0], '/', port[1])

        print()
        print('=' * 10, 'Deleted')
        for host, ports in scan_del.items():
            print(host, ':')
            for port in ports:
                   print(':::', port[0], '/', port[1])

  except Exception as l:
         print l
```

But the code throws :

```
first argument must be callable
```

Help me to use collection efficiently.

P.S : Trying to improve this way [How to compare dictionaries and see what changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851595/how-to-compare-dictionaries-and-see-what-changed/34852463?noredirect=1#comment57446991_34852463)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a callable (function / class / method) which will return a default value, not a default value itself.

Follow expression:

```
collections.defaultdict(set())
```

should be replaced with:

```
collections.defaultdict(set)
```

**UPDATE**

You need to create `defaultdict`s outside of the `for` loops:

```
self.old_port_dict = collections.defaultdict(set)
for s in self.prev_report.hosts:
    for x in s.get_open_ports():
        self.old_port_dict[s.address].add(x)

self.new_port_dict = collections.defaultdict(set)
for s in self.report.hosts:
    for x in s.get_open_ports():
        self.new_port_dict[s.address].add(x)
```

Comment: okay got it.. but then it says : 'collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'add' , and basically it means i am trying to add() a list of ports inside it.. basically add() is for a set /dict operation

Comment: @PythonFreak, Make a `defaultdict` outside of `for` loop: `self.old_port_dict = collections.defaultdict(set)`. updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: It says : 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'  , i believe due to `hosts = sorted(set(self.prev_report.hosts.keys() + self.report.hosts.keys()))`

Comment: @PythonFreak, Try `hosts = sorted(set(self.old_port_dict) | set(self.new_port_dict))`

Comment: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: list indices must be integers, not str
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "portwatch.py", line 308, in <module>
    report.comp_ports(config.get('system','scan_directory') + '/nmap-report-old.pkl')
  File "portwatch.py", line 145, in comp_ports
    scan_same[host] = self.prev_report.hosts[host] & self.report.hosts[host]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in your title, you need to do

```
collections.defaultdict(set)
```

You need to pass in something that can be instantiated. Passing in `collections.defaultdict(set())` is passing in something that *already is* instantiated.

Comment: It throws  :  after 'collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'add' .. how do i add the ports then ?

Comment: You need to treat it like a dictionary - you would do something like `x = collections.defaultdict(set)` and then `x['key'] = value`

Comment: i am not able to put it in code .. can u edit the loop 

            for s in self.prev_report.hosts:
                self.old_port_dict[s.address] = collections.defaultdict(set)
                for x in s.get_open_ports():
                    self.old_port_dict[s.address].add(x)

Comment: I think you want `old_port_dict` to be a defaultdict? In that case find where you do `self.old_port_dict = {}` and make it `self.old_port_dict = collections.defaultdict(set)`

Comment: Please look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851595/how-to-compare-dictionaries-and-see-what-changed/34852463?noredirect=1#comment57446991_34852463 , if that explains better ..i am unable to do so

Comment: If you want `self.old_port_dict[s.address].add(x)` to behave you're adding `x` to a set in a `defaultdict`, then simply take my suggestion from above. All you are doing is changing a `dict` to a `defaultdict` with that suggestion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101041/discussion-between-pythonfreak-and-martin-konecny).