# How to check if the dictionaries in a list are unique?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare

I have found some approaches, but unfortunately none, where it comes to the contents of Dictioranies. I hope this question is not a duplicate.

My Code:

```
import os
import csv
import glob

os.chdir("/Users/x/PycharmProjects/x")

listme = list()

for csvs in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    with open(csvs, mode="r") as csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

        for row in csv_reader:
            spek = {"name": row['name'], "party": row['group'], "term":row['term']}
            listme.append(spek)

for element in listme:
    print(element)
```

My Output (about 5000 elements):

```
{'name': 'Erwin Stahl', 'party': 'SPD', 'term': '9'}
{'name': 'Eugen Glombig', 'party': 'SPD', 'term': '9'}
{'name': 'Eugen von der Wiesche', 'party': 'SPD', 'term': '9'}
{'name': 'Ferdinand Tillmann', 'party': 'CDU', 'term': '9'}
{'name': 'Franz Amrehn', 'party': 'CDU', 'term': '9'}
{'name': 'Franz Handlos', 'party': 'CSU', 'term': '9'}
{'name': 'Franz Heinrich Krey', 'party': 'CDU', 'term': '9'}
{'name': 'Franz Josef Conrad', 'party': 'CDU', 'term': '9'}
```

How can I now check if in a term, a person of the same name exits from the same party only once? The name and party combination may occur, but not in the same term.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Knowing how to compare dictionaries might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911273/is-there-a-better-way-to-compare-dictionary-values/5635309#5635309

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My attempt (using `Counter` from `itertools`):

```
data = [{'name': 'Erwin Stahl', 'party': 'SPD', 'term': '9'},
{'name': 'Eugen Glombig', 'party': 'SPD', 'term': '9'},
{'name': 'Eugen von der Wiesche', 'party': 'SPD', 'term': '9'},
{'name': 'Ferdinand Tillmann', 'party': 'CDU', 'term': '9'},
{'name': 'Franz Amrehn', 'party': 'CDU', 'term': '9'},
{'name': 'Franz Handlos', 'party': 'CSU', 'term': '9'},
{'name': 'Franz Heinrich Krey', 'party': 'CDU', 'term': '9'},
{'name': 'Franz Josef Conrad', 'party': 'CDU', 'term': '9'}]

from collections import Counter

# Find duplicates based on 'name', 'party', 'term' - you can edit which keys you want to search for:
c = Counter((d['name'], d['party'], d['term']) for d in data)

new_data = []
for d in data:
    if c[(d['name'], d['party'], d['term'])] == 1:
        new_data.append(d)

print(new_data)
```

Comment: what happends in your solution, if a dublicate is founded?

Comment: @madik_atma If duplicate is found then it is not appended to new_data list.

Comment: thats mean, if I add a else and print there if != 1, they should print the dublicate row?

Comment: @madik_atma Yes, it depends on you what you want to do. In variable c you have number of duplicates (1 means no duplicates).

Comment: I want only catch possible dublicates, if theire exists. Because, I dont know it now :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn your `dict` objects into sth hashable. One option would be to turn their items into a `frozenset`:

```
s = set()
for d in listme:
  frz = frozenset(d.items())  # hashable data structure
  if frz in s:
    print(d)  # print duplicates
  else:
    s.add(frz)
```