# What's the time complexity of comparing if two dictionaries are equal in python?

Tags: python

I was working on a piece of code which requires dictionary comparison, I am curious about the time complexity of it. How does python implement dictionary comparison?

```
if Dict_1 == Dict_2:
    do something
```

Comment: It's a recursive lookup, depends on your dict values. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911273/is-there-a-better-way-to-compare-dictionary-values/5635309#5635309

Comment: If the recursion takes too long, try this DiffDicter library that is used to find the diff between two dictionaries. I have not timed it but may be faster -  https://dictdiffer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 2):

It is recursively compares pairs `key:value` in dicts, so *in theory* the comparison time should be equal to `number_of_all_recursive_items * time_to_check_one_item` (of course I am looking at the worst case - when dicts are equal and all pairs are checking). But in practice there is many pitfalls. Look at this picture:

[image]

It is the dict_length-time graph for flat dicts. Moreover, you can look at the comparison of the nested dict:

[image]

So you can't guarantee that your comparison will spend a particular amount of time. But **usually** - yes, there is a linear connection between recursive dict length and comparison time.